# Changing title bar in browser window of theme "Encounters Lite"

Tags: pages, title

I have an external php application for for genealogical research  ("TheNextGeneration", TNG) integrated into WP.  The integration plugin hooks the external content into a blank WP page and displays the genealogical data there.

Because it is always the same page, the browser window shows only the name of the WP page in the title bar.  Since each of the TNG pages comes with its own title, I like to have this information used instead.

The theme in use is "Encounters Lite" (if this is relevant).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Filter `wp_title`, get the current page title from your external app, and return that title.

Sample code:

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', function( $title ) {

    // check if it the correct page
    if ( ! is_my_external_app_page() )
        return $title;

    return get_title_from_external_app();
});
```

The implementation details are up to you.